# jHipster: Different versions on the 8080 and 9000 ports

Tags: java, jhipster

I executed "npm start" and "./mvnw" from my jHipster project folder on the different consoles.

Why contents on the http://localhost:9000 and http://localhost:8080 are different? http://localhost:8080  shows more old version of content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you do a prod build, it  puts the frontend files on target folder and package all in a war/jar. When accessing on port 8080, you are fetching that packaged frontend inside the war/jar, while for port 9000, its proxying the stuff you started with `npm start`.  Do a `./mvnw clean` or simply remove target folder.

Also you can compile frontend to have that files updated.

> When using Angular 2+ if you need to do a clean run with webpack
>   compilation enabled for dev profile you can pass the webpack param as
>   below
>
> `./mvnw -Pdev,webpack`

This way you will have updated the served content on 8080 port.

Comment: admlz635 Thanks for the sensible explanation!